# Adobe CC Post-Production Workflow (Story, Prelude etc.)

Tags: video-editor, editing, software, workflow, adobe

I've never understood the post-production workflow Adobe has designed.

I understand the steps from the editing stage onwards (assume this is a large enough production to require all steps):

1. Premiere: Ingest footage into bins, assistant edit, possible assembly edit
2. Premiere: Edit to picture lock-off
3. After Effects: VFX/Grading

   - Alternatively, use SpeedGrade for grading
4. Audition: Sound Mix
5. Premiere: Bring final grade, sound mix together
6. Media Encoder: Render project

However, I don't understand the workflow of Adobe Story, Prelude, and how they enhance the established workflow.

---

#### Update 1:

I should mention, I have done some research previously, but Adobe's site is delightfully dense and explanatory.

From [Adobe's site](http://www.adobe.com/au/products/prelude.html), Prelude is described as:

> **Metadata, megafast**
>
> Work faster with smarter video ingest and logging.

How does this help the workflow, what does it add to the process?

---

*Under our [rules for asking questions](https://video.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) a constructive question that "inspires answers that explain “why” and “how”" is acceptable.*

Answer (score 1):

Your workflow is a little off from how it is designed by Adobe.

Step 1: Adobe Story: You build your script and can break it into shots that you need to capture before you even start shooting.  This can then work as the blueprint to plan out shooting of the project.

Step 2: Adobe Prelude: I believe you can preconfigure a shot list that needs to be captured with meta data about the scenes.  Prelude can either be used for live capture or can be used to Ingest and organize footage on site during shooting.  Think of it a bit like Lightroom for Video.  It's intended to organize the shots so that they can more effectively be reviewed and pulled up during shooting and post production.

Step 3: Premiere: Rough edit, start laying out clips and getting the flow of the piece together.

Step 4/5: After Effects: any touch up or effects work that needs to be done on individual clips can be processed through After Effects and sent back to Premiere.  This could also be done before rough editing, but is probably easier after/during.  This may also include color grading or SpeedGrade may be used.

Step 4/5: Audition: basically the same thing as After Effects, but on the sound track/audio side on a clip level.

Step 6: Premiere: Once assets are finalized, final edit can occur to produce the finished timings for the video.

Step 7/8: Audition: Mastering, finish the audio and sound-tracking for the entire finished video to make sure it flows well from one clip to another.

Step 7/8: After Effects or Speed Grade: Perform final color grading to ensure the entire film flows well together.

Step 9: Media Encoder or Encore: Prepare final output format, either encoding for the web or building a DVD and/or Blueray disk for release.

Comment: Hmm, I don't like the concept of going to grading, sound design or VFX before having final cut, that is the exact final timings for shots etc. But then, I don't have buckets of money for do-overs when a scene or shot's length changes.

Comment: @nchpmn - I'm not talking anything final on those steps.  Just basic stuff.  Getting it close enough that you can see how it flows.  It's just a rough pass.  You can also certainly make alterations to the order of things as fits your workflow, the big thing was just trying to show how Prelude and Story fit and pointing out that After Effects is actually the stronger grading tool for doing the overall process.